# Android execute method when ListPreference is selected

Tags: android, list, methods, preference

how can I execute a method as soon as a user selects an option in a ListPreference?

Comment: not a clear question, be more precise

Comment: @Apurva what is not clear about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go that way:

```
ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_name");
pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
   yourAction();
}
```